# ruby error when install ceeding,(Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)

Tags: ruby, ceedling

i just installed the ruby 2.7.8,i never used it before and want to install the ceedling.
But when i run the command `gem install ceedling -v 0.31.1`,always got a an error

```
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/win32/registry.rb:910:in `encode': U+7F51 to CP850 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to CP850 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

what kind of problem is it and how to solve it?

Comment: Seems like your terminal is using CP850 as its encoding. Try changing it to UTF-8.